# Having spacing issues with IE9 & FF11 for OS X

Tags: html, css, firefox, xhtml, internet-explorer-9

Was doing some testing with a design I coded and it works well in `FF 13`, `Chrome 21`, `IE 7/8` & `Opera 11.62` for `Windows` and `Safari 5.1` for `OS X`.

I only have WinXP so I had to use Adbobe Browserlab to test for OS X and IE 9.

Problem is in `IE9` and `FF 11` for `OS X` the nav seems to drop down like it's too wide; but it's not, I have checked it.

The URL is: http://www.condorstudios.com/stuff/temp/

**Just tried the below changes but still no change in those browsers..**

```
#header .nav ul {
    width: 992px; // New
    margin: 0px auto; // Changed to 0px margin, but is now centered to get the same effect
}

#header .nav li ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: auto; // Needed to add so it didn't inherit width from above
    /*left: -1px;*/ // Removed
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `.nav li { display: inline; }` to your CSS.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. But thanks, I should of had them as inline anyway haha

Comment: Try specifying a width for the sub ul.

Comment: @BillyMoat I can't really do that as I don't know what width's they are going to be if options get added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Seems those browsers didn't seem to like the `text-indent` I had on the contact button, so by removing..

```
#header .nav li.contact {
    text-indent: 1px;
}
```

It now works!